# production.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\Builder\SiteController does not exist' in compiled.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to immerge two Laravel 5.2 projects the first one is using Api and the second doesn't. I copied all the controllers, the views and routes to the first project, and in the database i added the other tables using migrations and models but i immerged the user table by adding columns that doesn't exist in the first table, so i have one user for both projects.
I also added all the routes but i want to use the api middleware of the first project on the dashboard page of the second project so i added the controller in the api folder inside a folder named builder and write the route like that :

```
// Routes.php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    // Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () {
    Route::get('', 'HomeController@index');

    //added for testing builder
    Route::get('/dashboard','Builder\SiteController@getDashboard');
```

And yet i'm getting this error, This is the function that shows the error in compiled.php :

```
public function signatureParameters($subClass = null)
    {
        $action = $this->getAction();
        if (is_string($action['uses'])) {
            list($class, $method) = explode('@', $action['uses']);
            $parameters = (new ReflectionMethod($class, $method))->getParameters();
        } else {
            $parameters = (new ReflectionFunction($action['uses']))->getParameters();
        }
        return is_null($subClass) ? $parameters : array_filter($parameters, function ($p) use($subClass) {
            return $p->getClass() && $p->getClass()->isSubclassOf($subClass);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `SiteController` ?

Comment: yes i placed the site controller in the exact place where i mentioned in the route file and i changed the namespace too